# Android NotificationCompat.InboxStyle like a table

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to show notifications like in a table with horizontal cell-padding?

[image]

I created this example with tabs `\t` but i want to style the first "column" and because of not knowing the exactly width after that, i think this is not a good option.

Is there a table-like solution to show notification text?

Answer (score 0):

You're left with implementing your own notification layout.

Use a `RemoteView` and inflate it as described in the API Guide : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification